# why does my string give such an output when i convert it?

Tags: c++, string

What i need to get is the 5 as an integer from the string "510" however i have been getting 53 no matter what i have tried?Any ideas on what i should do?

The code:

```
string x = "510";
     cout<<x ;//output == 510
     int number = x[0];
     cout<<number //output == 53 i have also tried stoi() same thing happened
```

Comment: Have you tried `cout<<x[0];`?

Comment: 53 is 5 in ASCII. You are taking the first char in a string.

Comment: `int number= x[0]-'0';` becaus a char is not an int.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie i want to convert it to an integer to multiply it afterwards.Yes i have tried but isnt it still a string when i do x[0]?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie why exactly do you do x[0] - '0' i just tried it and it works however i would like to know how that works exactly

Comment: What do you think the string "510" is? You need to understand that before you can convert anything extracted from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a C++ guru, but:

```
cout<<x;        //output the string x
cout<<x[0];     // output the first char of the string
```

and:

```
int number= x[0]-'0';  // convert the first char to a number
cout << number;        // print the number
```

`x[0]-'0'` converts the ASCII char `'5'`, which is ASCII code 53, to an int because the ASCII code of `'0'` is 48 and 53 - 48 = 5.

This is a normality of the ASCII encoding. The digits 0123456789 are contiguous in the encoding and their codes are 48,49,...57, so for any digit character `c`, `c-'0'` yields the integer value of the digit.

Comment: C++ (and C) require digits 0123456789 to be contiguous in every encoding that a string is compiled to. The fact that one such encoding is ASCII is not relevant.The one that the asker is compiling to (complier flag "-fexec-charset" or similar) could be relevant but isn't in this code.

Comment: @TomBlodget, I am not aware that this is a _language_ requirement. How can a language dictate what external encoding schemes must be? Do you have a reference? What does it say about ABCDEF (parts of hex encoding)?

Comment: Just the decimal digits: ["value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal
digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf). It dictates rules for the _execution character set_ (which is what literal characters and strings in the source code end up as). So, you can write a program that relies on these rules.